# HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'myUser' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring

I have a problem. Web.xml does not load the Welcome.jsp and also Am I correct in writing teh controller @RequestMapping value, I assume it is the URL and must map the req to the mentioned jsp.

### Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
<context-param>  
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>  
<param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>  
</context-param> 
<listener>  
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>  
</listener> 
<listener>
<listener-lass>org.apache.tiles.extras.complete.CompleteAutoloadTilesListener
</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>  
<servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>  
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
</servlet> 
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Tiles Dispatch Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.apache.tiles.web.util.TilesDispatchServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>  
<servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>  
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Tiles Dispatch Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.tiles</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list> 
<welcome-file>/WEB-INF/pages/Welcome.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

### mvc-dispatcher.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans       
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="com.dev.controller" />  
<bean  
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
<property name="prefix">  
<value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>  
</property>  
<property name="suffix">  
<value>.jsp</value>  
</property>  
</bean>  
</beans>
```

### Welcome.jsp

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
    <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
    <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
    <tiles:insertDefinition name="myapp.homepage" />
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="welcomeTitle" class="title">
    <h1>Health Care Simulation - Welcome</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="centerBody" class="body">
    <form:form method="post" action="Welcome" modelAttribute="myUser">
    Enter Team Name:<font color="red"><form:errors path="teamName" /></font>
    <form:input path="teamName" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form:form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

### WelcomeController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/welcome")
@Controller
public class WelcomeController {

    @ModelAttribute("myUser")

    public TeamName getLoginForm(@RequestParam String user) {
        System.out.println("test");
        TeamName myUser = new TeamName();
        myUser.setTeamName(user);
        return myUser;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showForm(@ModelAttribute("myUser") TeamName myUser)       
            /*Map model*/ {
        System.out.println("test1");
        //myUser.addAttribute("myUser",myUser ); 
        /*TeamName myUser = new TeamName();
        model.put("myUser", myUser);*/
        return "myUser";
    }
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String validateForm(
        @ModelAttribute("myUser") @Valid TeamName myUser,
        BindingResult result, Map model) {
        System.out.println("test1");
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "welcome";
        }

        model.put("myUser", myUser);

        return "success";

    }

}
```

### TeamName.java

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
public class TeamName {

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 1, max = 20)
    private String teamName;

    public String getTeamName() {
        return teamName;
    }

    public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check the compilation errors. Also check the case of filenames like Web.xml, Welcome.jsp. these should be in all-small cases (web.xml, welcome.jsp).

Comment: there are no compilation errors as such

Comment: throws:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'myUser' available as request attribute

Comment: The exception you're seeing is because the model attribute is missing. You should add a `model.put("myUser", new MyUser());` in your `GET` handler method so the form can bind to it.

Comment: Changed to following:

Comment: Changed to following:
@RequestMapping(value = "/welcome")
@Controller
public class WelcomeController { 
@ModelAttribute("myUser")
public TeamName getLoginForm(@RequestParam String user{System.out.println("test");
TeamName myUser = new TeamName();
myUser.setTeamName(user);
return myUser;
}@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showForm(@ModelAttribute("myUser") TeamName myUser)   
{model.put("myUser", myUser);return "myUser";}

Comment: @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String validateForm(@ModelAttribute("myUser") @Valid TeamName myUser,BindingResult result, Map model) {
if (result.hasErrors()) {return "welcome";}model.put("myUser",myUser);return "success";}}

Answer (score 0):

I think that You should return just `return "Welcome";` and not the `return "Welcome.jsp";`, because mvc-dispatcher.xml You already created suffix for the webpage which is .jsp in that case

and in order to get to the page you enter in You browser localhost:8080/Welcome.jsp (of course if You are using local host serwer and port 8080)

Comment: I made following changes and thesam error page not found:  RequestMapping(value = "/Welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showForm(Map model) {
        return "Welcome";
    }
 @RequestMapping(value = "/Welcome", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String validateForm(
        @ModelAttribute("myUser") @Valid TeamName myUser,
        BindingResult result, Map model) {
 
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "Welcome";
        }
In Jsp:  <form:form method="post" action="Welcome" commandName="myUser">

Comment: judging from the error it seems like the problem might be in the JSP form `In Jsp: <form:form method="post" action="localhost:8080/Welcome" commandName="myUser">` - > in other words, action should indicate some webpage in You case with /Welcome in the end

Comment: Thank you for ur reply! One consideration, even when I try to run the welcome.jsp on server, it http://localhost:8080/HealthyCommunitySimulator/welcome.jsp, it returns status: 404. Is this something to do with controller view?

Comment: Why do You try localhost:8080/HealthyCommunitySimulator/welcome.jsp ? it is not mapped that is why You got 404, it should be like that base (localhost:8080) + requestMapping from controller (in Your case /Welcome) = localhost:8080/Welcome

Comment: i NOW GET THIS ERROR-SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/HealthyCommunitySimulator] threw exception [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'myUser' available as request attribute] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'myUser' available as request attribute

Answer (score 0):

@RequestMapping will only be processed if a corresponding HandlerMapping (for type level annotations) and/or HandlerAdapter (for method level annotations) is present in the dispatcher. This is the case by default.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Am I missing anything in the controller.java